# Camel CDI CXF - Jetty configuration

Tags: java, jetty, apache-camel, cxf, cdi

I am using Apache Camel with CDI and start my application using the main from `org.apache.camel.cdi.Main`.

To start an actual CxfEndpoint I have following code:

```
  @Produces
  @Named("cxfendpoint")
  public CxfEndpoint createEndpoint() {
    CxfEndpoint endpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
    endpoint.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:8181/cxf");
    endpoint.setServiceClass(WSPortType.class);
    endpoint.setWsdlURL("foo.wsdl");
    endpoint.setCamelContext(new CdiCamelContext());
    return endpoint;
  }
```

This starts a jetty instance listening on port 8181.

I want now to configure this jetty instance like you do with cxf standalone, e.g. with a file `cxf.xml`.
Finally, I want to start a second CxfEndpoint using the same jetty instance by setting the endpoint address to just `"/cxf"`.

How would I do this?